# Get an image field of a specific size in REST API

Tags: media, 8

How can i get an specific size of an image in the REST API?

I have created a view that displays as a **REST export**, the format of the view is:

- Format: Serializer
- Show: Entity

The image field is shown as:

```
field_image [
  {
    "target_id": "9",
    "alt": "Foo",
    "title": "",
    "width": "2304",
    "height": "3456",
    "target_type": "file",
    "target_uuid": "99d6732e-e9c3-4e05-be87-d2868e9f149d",
    "url": "http://mysite/sites/default/files/2016-12/foo-image-1313021.jpg"
  }
]
```

Where can I set the type of style(/admin/config/media/image-styles) that should return me in JSON format?

If I change the format by:

- Format: Serializer
- Show: Fields

It returns me the img tag.

Comment: isn't the "width" and "height" the size? Have you tried to `REWRITE RESULTS` of those fields?

Comment: @NoSssweat In the "Image styles" /admin/config/media/image-styles there are 11 types of images sizes. How can I get a specific size and not the original image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the next configuration of my REST View. Not ideal but works...

FORMAT

- Format: Serializer
- Show: Fields

FIELDS

- Content: Title
- Content: Image
- Content: Data

The settings of the image field are:

- Formatter: Image
- **Image style: Max 650x650**

The post is returned as:

```
{
    "title": "Foo",
    "field_image": "<img src=\"/sites/default/files/styles/max_650x650/public/2016-12/foo-1313021.jpg?itok=UiQ2F7lI\" width=\"433\" height=\"650\" alt=\"Bar\" typeof=\"foaf:Image\" class=\"img-responsive\" />",
    "field_event_date": "2016-12-02T13:04:03"
}
```

And i apply the next Javascript function in the frontend:

```
// Get image tag source attribute
var getImgSrc = function( tag ) {
    var rex = /<img[^>]+src="?([^"\s]+)"?[^>]*\/>/g;
    var m = rex.exec( tag );
    return m[1];
}
var src = getImgSrc( post_content.field_image );
```